# "Validate With" option or Setting up XML validation scenarios in Eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, validation, eclipse-plugin

Are there any plugins for eclipse or a way that would allow me to set-up validation scenarios, or tell eclipse to validate xml files without adding paths to the xsd/dtd files to the xml itself?

I know Oxygen/XMLSpy are capable of this.